# Finding the coordinates to randomly distribute images on a display without overlap

Tags: python, python-2.7, screen

I have the following code which randomly generates a list of (X,Y) tuples:

```
import random
coords = []
for i in range(10):
    x = random.randint(85,939)
    y = random.randint(75,693)
    coords.append((x,y))
```

In the final list, the X values of each tuple are considered to overlap if the absolute difference between them is less then 85, and the Y values are considered to overlap if the absoulte difference is less than 75. How can I make sure that none of the tuples in the final list will overlap in *both* dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** way to do this is to just keep sampling and discarding coordinates which will create overlap. This will however become very inefficient when you come close to filling the available space. If that's not an issue you should go with this solution.

A bit more efficient and as far as I can tell statistically equivalent is to sample one coordinate, like the row, first. Then compute the occupied area in that row and sample from the remaining positions if there are any.

To avoid the same problem as in the easy solution, if there are no available spaces in a row, it should be removed from the possible sampling outcomes for the row (plus the margin of 75 in both directions).

Ideally, you don't compute the occupied regions each time but you keep a mapping from the row to the occupied space in that row and the amount of non-full rows and just update this mapping when inserting new images. You will need storage for *n_rows + 1* extra numbers.

To clarify: When sampling from a restricted space just subtract the occupied positions and get a sampling result *n*. Then find the correct position for *n* by walking along the coordinate axis *n* steps, skipping all the occupied positions.